# SQL error code: #1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql

doing some SQL'ing and trying to arrange my data. I did the codes etc. but I got a #1064 error (problem with syntax) could someone check my code and tell me where I'm wrong :)

```
 $database = new connection();
    $database = $database->Connect("companyhouse");

    $statement = $database->prepare(" SELECT * 
                                      FROM companyhouse_23 
                                      ORDER BY Incorporation_Date DESC
                                      WHERE 
                                        incorporation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
                                        AND County = 'Sussex'
                                        AND County LIKE '%Sussex%'
                                      ");
    $statement->execute();
    $Results = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

In my eyes it's all good but obviously not eh? haha

Comment: order by should be last part of the query

Comment: Additionally, the `LIKE` test is redundant as you are already testing the _exact_ value of `County`

Comment: @IanRoberts it isn't redundant because Sussex is used for east sussex and west sussex

Comment: You're testing County for both `= 'Sussex'` **AND** `LIKE '%Sussex%'` - anything that satisfies the former trivially satisfies the latter as well. Maybe the AND should be an OR instead (with appropriate parentheses added)?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Order By` clause before than `Where` clause. `Order By` clause must be last clause of any query. Make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $statement = $database->prepare(" SELECT 
                                         * 
                                      FROM 
                                         companyhouse_23 
                                      WHERE 
                                        incorporation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
                                        AND County = 'Sussex'
                                        AND County LIKE '%Sussex%'
                                      ORDER BY 
                                         Incorporation_Date DESC
                                      ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the query like this. `ORDER BY`  should be used after `WHERE`

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    companyhouse_23 
WHERE 
   incorporation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
   AND County = 'Sussex'
   AND County LIKE '%Sussex%'
ORDER BY 
    Incorporation_Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  companyhouse_23 
WHERE incorporation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
   AND  County='Sussex' 
   AND County LIKE '%Sussex%' 
   ORDER BY Incorporation_Date DESC
```

2 things to note in your query:

1. Order by should be last part of your query.
2. In your where clause you are using county = 'Susses' and county like '%Sussex%' (This condition will only return rows having county='Sussex' (Redundant like clause)
   Use only one based on you requirement (if exact match is reqd use = else Like clause)